# How to merge dataframe into another dataframe that created from product of first dataframe in pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with column A,B  then I have function foo(B) taking parameter B from the first dataframe returning number of rows based on value of B ,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [1,1, 2, 3]), ('B', [4,3, 5, 6])])
def foo(B):
    sX = pd.Series(np.random.randn(B))
    sY = pd.Series(np.random.randn(B))
    return pd.DataFrame.from_items([('X', sX.tolist()), ('Y', sY.tolist())])
foo(4)
foo(3)
```

I ultimately want to create a new dataframe that merge the two table.

[image]
;;;;;;
[image]

I want my output to look like this below ...
 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group data frame `x` by columns `A` and `B`, then generate data frame for each group using `apply` method:

```
(x.groupby(['A', 'B']).apply(lambda g: foo(g.B))
  .reset_index(level=2, drop=True).reset_index())
```

[image]

Comment: Glad it helps! :)

Comment: Actually , one question.. I don't understand level , why did you put level = 2 ? "Only remove the given levels from the index. "  what does it mean ?

Comment: `.reset_index(level=..., drop=True)` is a convenient way to remove index at a specific level, in this problem, the newly generated data frame has it's own index which will be combined into a multi-index in the result. Use this syntax to remove it since you don't need it, ignore this otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [1,1, 2, 3]), ('B', [4,3, 5, 6])])

def foo(B):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(B,2), columns=['X','Y'])
    df['tmp'] = B
    return df

x.merge(pd.concat([foo(4), foo(3)]), left_on='B', right_on='tmp', how='left').drop('tmp',1)
```